# Could we extend isomorphisms between cohomologies of h-injective complexes to h-injective complexes themselves?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, chain-complexes, injective-modules

Let $R$ be an associative ring with unit and $I$ be a complex of $R$-modules. We call $I$ is h-injective if for any acyclic complex $T$ of $R$-modules, the mapping complex $\text{Hom}_R(T,I)$ is acyclic too.

Now let $I$ and $J$ two h-injective complexes of $R$-modules. Let $H^{\cdot}(I)$ and $H^{\cdot}(J)$ be the cohomologies of $I$ and $J$.

> > My question is: suppose we have maps of $R$-modules $f^n:H^n(I)\overset{\sim}{\to}H^n(J)$ for each $n$, could we define a quasi-isomorphism
> >     $$
> > \phi: I\overset{\sim}{\to} J
> > $$
> >     such that $H^n(\phi)=f^n$ for each $n$? We may add some condition such as both $I$ and $J$ are componentwisely injective and have bounded cohomologies.